# How to create a table with just an ID and years with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm making a website to keep track of people that are registered and paid to be part of a community. I want to be able to see who was registered in 2014, 2015, 2016 and so on. I was thinking about making a table with the columns: user_id and year to keep search for who was registered and paid in a certain year. Or vice versa where I can search what years a certain user have been registered and paid. How would I create that table using code first?

Comment: hint: you will not save much resources if you'll keep only year instead of saving full registration date

Comment: [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) may help